# HTML5 Offline storage not working

Tags: html, local-storage, offline-caching

This is the code provided by the W3C example for offline web storage : http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function renderNote(row) {
          console.log(row);
        }
        function reportError(source, message) {
          console.log("err");
        }

        function renderNotes() {
          db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes(title TEXT, body TEXT)', 
              []);
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Notes', [], function(tx, rs) {
              for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
                renderNote(rs.rows[i]);
              }
            });
          });
        }

        function insertNote(title, text) {
          db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Notes VALUES(?, ?)', [ title, text ],
              function(tx, rs) {
                // …
              },
              function(tx, error) {
                reportError('sql', error.message);
              });
          });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is no console log output at all. What is the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instantiation of the db and execution of the function was missing.

Check this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax5d7/4/

**JavaScript**

```
var db = openDatabase("notes", "", "The Example Notes App!", 1048576);

function renderNote(row) {
    console.log(row);
}

function reportError(source, message) {
    console.log("err");
}

function renderNotes() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes(title TEXT, body TEXT)', 
        []);

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Notes', [], function(tx, rs) {
            for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
                renderNote(rs.rows[i]);
            }
        });
    });
}

function insertNote(title, text) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Notes VALUES(?, ?)', [ title, text ],
        function(tx, rs) {
            // …
        },
        function(tx, error) {
            reportError('sql', error.message);
        });
    });
}

renderNotes();
```

**Even more simplistic**

```
var db = openDatabase("notes", "", "The Example Notes App!", 10000);

db.transaction(function(t) {
    //t.executeSql("DROP TABLE Notes");
    t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes(title TEXT, body TEXT)");
    t.executeSql("INSERT INTO Notes VALUES(?, ?)", [ 'title', 'content' ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please note that http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ is no longer being maintained and support may be dropped in future versions.

http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage is the way to go...

See caniuse.com for browser support table.

Comment: webstorage is not a replacement for webSQL IndexedDB is. localStore is a key-value datastore with very limited use. IndexedDB right now is less suported than webSQL and in general sucks, try to do a left join in IndexedDB and you will know what I mean.